# Lookup Field in Extended Reports

Tags: extension, civireport

I've created a relationship report through the Extended Reports extension but have run into a challenging situation.  I want the report to show detailed information (in this case, the name of the leading office) rather than the ID number stored in the table.  Is there a way to make this happen without creating custom code?  We're using 5.16.4.  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: In case you don't get a quick answer, worth mentioning what CMS you are using as some reports are easier to build with CMS tools, eg Views for Drupal.

Comment: Good point.  I should have mentioned that we are currently using Drupal 7.

Comment: if you are using Drupal then i would build this with Views myself

Comment: Ok.  We'll look into that option.  Thanks.